# Why is git fetch not fetching any tags?

Tags: git, tags, git-fetch

I have created a sandbox git repository containing a few commits and a couple of tags, one lightweight and one annotated:

```
> mkdir one; cd one; git init

> touch a.txt; git add a.txt; git commit -m"a.txt"

> touch b.txt; git add b.txt; git commit -m"b.txt"
> git tag light

> touch c.txt; git add c.txt; git commit -m"c.txt"
> git tag -a annot -m"annot"
```

I now create a second repository and fetch from the first:

```
> mkdir two; cd two; git init

> git remote add one <...>/one
> git fetch one master
remote: Counting objects: 9, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (9/9), done.
From <...>/one
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> one/master
```

Why have neither of the tags been fetched? I expected they would be, based on [the documentation for `git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch):

> By default, any tag that points into the histories being fetched is also fetched; the effect is to fetch tags that point at branches that you are interested in.

Comment: did you try `git fetch --all`

Comment: I'm nearly certain Git's tag handling has changed significantly over the years, so: which Git *version* are you running? (And, if this is on two separate machines, what URL scheme, http:// vs git:// vs ssh://, are you using and give both machines' Git versions...)

Comment: @crai - Both `git fetch --tags one master` and plain `git fetch one` fetch the `one/master` branch and both `light` and `annot` tags. However, `git fetch one master` does not fetch the tags - I am trying to understand why.

Comment: @torek - I am using the latest git version, 2.11.0. Both repositories are on the same machine, using the `file://` URL scheme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit, Jan 2020, per [Tim Bunce's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813643/why-is-git-fetch-not-fetching-any-tags/41815610?noredirect=1#comment105993855_41815610): the behavior was deemed to be a bug and changed in Git 2.20 to be more sensible.  The tests below are for significantly older versions of Git.

---

Updated with new interesting informational bits.  I put this into a shell script for easy testing:

```
mkdir ttwo && cd ttwo && git init && git remote add one file://[path]
```

(and then I remove `ttwo` after running a test).

Hence each test below is run in the new empty `ttwo`.  I am also using Git 2.10.1 here, but there should be no significant differences with 2.11 (while there are definitely significant differences compared with Git 1.7, which is still shipping with certain Linux distributions...).

First, let's `git fetch` with *no* refspecs:

```
$ git fetch one
remote: Counting objects: 8, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 8 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (8/8), done.
From file://[path]
 * [new branch]      master     -> one/master
 * [new tag]         annot      -> annot
 * [new tag]         light      -> light
```

This is with Git version 2.10.1, with both repositories on the same machine, and using either `file:///home/...` or `/home/...`.  Both fetches (`rm -rf texp2` in between as needed) picked up both tags.

Now let's run it with the single refspec `master`.  From here on I'll leave out the `remote:` through `From:` stuff, just show what branches and/or tags get updated:

```
$ git fetch one master
[snip]
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> one/master
```

Here's what happens if we use `master:master`, which requires adding `--update-head-ok`:

```
$ git fetch one --update-head-ok master:master
 * [new branch]      master     -> master
 * [new tag]         annot      -> annot
 * [new branch]      master     -> one/master
 * [new tag]         light      -> light
```

Aha, now we get tags!

Here's what happens if we fetch `master` but write it to `refs/remotes/origin/master`:

```
$ git fetch one master:refs/remotes/origin/master
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
 * [new tag]         annot      -> annot
 * [new branch]      master     -> one/master
 * [new tag]         light      -> light
```

#### There is a pattern emerging: we have to write to some local ref(s)

Let's fetch `master` to `x` and `light` to `dark` (I tried `foo` to `bar` but that doesn't work because `foo` does not exist in repo one):

```
$ git fetch one master:x light:dark
 * [new branch]      master     -> x
 * [new tag]         light      -> dark
 * [new tag]         annot      -> annot
 * [new tag]         light      -> light
 * [new branch]      master     -> one/master
```

Now let's fetch `master` to *nothing*, which we know fails standalone, but fetch `light` to `dark`:

```
$ git fetch one master light:dark
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new tag]         light      -> dark
 * [new tag]         annot      -> annot
 * [new tag]         light      -> light
 * [new branch]      master     -> one/master
```

And one last test:

```
$ git fetch one master light
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * tag               light      -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> one/master
```

This did not write to our tags, only to `FETCH_HEAD`, plus the usual opportunistic remote-tracking branch update.

The bottom line appears to be that, when giving explicit refspecs, we must write *at least one* local ref.  Fetching with *no* refspecs works, because that uses the default refspecs in the config file plus the default tags.  Fetching with some refspec(s) that write to a local ref works.  Fetching with some refspec(s) that only write to `FETCH_HEAD` fails.  This seems like a bug, but it's not clear what the intent of the code in Git is, and Git's tag update code is horribly twisty.

Comment: Using `git fetch one` like this fetches the `one/master` branch and both `light` and `annot` tags for me too. However, I was expecting `git fetch one master` to also fetch the tags - I am trying to understand why it does not.

Comment: Oh, I see, you gave an *explicit refspec*. The tags code inside Git is very twisty, so I don't know *why* that fails, but obviously it does.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem using `git fetch one master`?

Comment: Yes. Works with no refspec, fails with a refspec with no local name. Will update answer with more.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing all these tests! Based on the evidence, it does indeed seem that to get the tags, at least one explicit refspec must have an explicit destination. It therefore looks like the way to fetch `master` along with the relevant tags would be `git fetch one master:refs/remotes/one/master`. Is this the command you would recommend using in place of `git fetch one master`?

Comment: @user200783: yes, assuming the standard (non-mirror-style, no other funny business with the `fetch` refspec in the config) configuration. If you wanted to be extra paranoid in a script, you could run `git config --get-all remote.one.fetch` and parse the resulting output. I probably would just `git fetch one master:refs/remotes/one/master`. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. There is no unusual configuration involved, so I will just use `git fetch one master:refs/remotes/one/master`. Do you think the fact that this behaves differently to `git fetch one master` should be reported as a bug in Git?

Comment: Seems like it's either a behavior bug or a documentation bug, yes. There's no mention that default-tags is defeated by a remote-only refspec...

Comment: Great thanks @torek; I would have never guessed why related tags are not fetched.  What the manual says on the matter is bs.

Comment: FYI The behaviour changed in git 2.20 per https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch "Since Git version 2.20, fetching to update refs/tags/* works the same way as when pushing. I.e. any updates will be rejected without + in the refspec (or --force)."

Answer (score 19):

Not a true answer but I got here via Google search because `git fetch` was not pulling my tags (and usually does). So this is for anyone else in the same boat who stumbles upon this very similarly worded question.

I was able to manually pull the tag with: `git fetch --tags`

Comment: This answer helped. I would have expected `git fetch --all` to get tags as well, but it didn't. This did. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Same problem here. Bizarre that `git fetch` mysteriously does not always fetch all tags as it usually does.

Comment: is this a bug in git or?

Comment: `git fetch` fetched all tags but one. `git fetch --tags` fetched all tags. Now even if I delete all tags, `git fetch` will correctly fetch them all. Interesting.