# Fetching a remote tag

Tags: git

I have used following command to fetch a remote tag, it completed successfully by fetching the remote objects.

```
git fetch origin <tag name >
```

After that gave following command to switch to tag,  but it gave `error: pathspec` error.

```
git checkout <tag name>
```

Now I tried following command.

```
git fetch --tags
```

After that the command, `git checkout <tag name>`  executed successfully.

Can you help to understand during `git fetch origin <tag name>` why the tag was not fetched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`git fetch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) does mention:

> By default, tags that point at objects that are downloaded from the remote repository are fetched and stored locally

However: if you are fetching a refspec referencing a tag name directly, you are actually fetching what the tag points to, *but*: **you don't specify the refspec *destination***.
So you see only:

```
 * tag aTag -> FETCH_HEAD
```

The tag reference is copied to `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, but not created locally.

As opposed to `git fetch --tags`, which is the equivalent of using the refspec `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`: source (the `tags/*`) *and* destination (in your repo: `tags/*`) are specified, the remote tags are created locally.

See more at "[A git tag doesn't seem to be available after explicitly fetching the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47947825/6309)"

A `git fetch origin refs/tags/<tag name>:refs/tags/<tag name>` would have worked.
The `git checkout <tag name>` would not have yield "`error: pathspec '<tag name>' did not match any file(s) known to git`"

Comment: I have cloned `https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c.git` and tried to fetch the tag `git fetch refs/tag/1.3.4:refs/tag/1.3.4`,but it is giving error. The clone command and fetch command outputs are [pasted](https://pastebin.com/W3VtB6ea)

Comment: What does a git fetch --tags, followed by git tag -l returns? Do you see your 1.3.4 tag in there?

Comment: `git tag -l` lists the tag 1.3.4. The command output [pasted](https://pastebin.com/H0w4Qj5w)

Comment: I have added `fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*` in .git/config then `git fetch origin 1.3.4` was successful, [output](https://pastebin.com/h3Pc4kHM). Before modifying `.git/config` file, I have tried with `git fetch refs/tags/1.3.4:refs/remotes/origin/tags/1.3.4`, but it gave error `fatal: 'refs/tags/1.3.4:refs/remotes/origin/tags/1.3.4' does not appear to be a git repository`.

Comment: @RaviA It was `git fetch refs/tags/<tag name>:refs/tags/<tag name>`, with `tags/`, not `tag/`. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but for me it expects `origin` also along with `tags` i.e `git fetch origin refs/tags/1.3.4:refs/tags/1.3.4`. May be my internal settings issue due to which it is expecting remote repository name `origin` also.