# Fetch new tags but don't update old ones in git

Tags: git, git-tag, git-fetch

In git, putting a `+` in front of a refspec is supposed to mean "allow overwrites" - i.e., the difference between

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

and

```
git fetch origin refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Is that the latter form will not update a remote branch unless it is a fast-forward merge from the existing remote branch.

It seems that this doesn't work for tags, though. Whether I add a `+` in front or not, an updated tag in the remote will update the local tag as soon as I fetch, and the only indication something has happened is a `t` flag for a "successful tag update".

Here's a simple reproduction (on Linux/cygwin/MinGW):

```
mkdir repo1
cd repo1
git init
for i in `seq 10`; do echo $i > $i.txt; git add $i.txt; git commit -m "$i"; done
git branch branch10
git tag tag10
cd ..
git clone repo1 repo2
cd repo1
git branch -f branch10 branch10^  # move branch10 one commit back
git tag -f tag10 tag10^  # move tag10 one commit back
cd ../repo2
git fetch origin refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

The output of the last command is:

```
From C:/Users/israel.tsadok/Documents/test/repo1
 ! [rejected]        branch10   -> origin/branch10  (non-fast-forward)
 t [tag update]      tag10      -> tag10
```

The commit gets rejected, as expected, but the tag gets merrily updated.

I would like to be able to fetch only new tags from a remote, without worrying about changing existing tags. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: related but different: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41815610/1256452 (and, given how twisty the tag ref update code is, I suspect there are numerous bugs lurking here)

Comment: When a tag points to a commit, it doesn't move, not considering force-update or delete-and-recreate. So fast-forward or non-fast-forward is meaningless to tags and thus it's reasonable that "+" doesn't work for a tag refspec. You could run `git tag` to list the local tags, run `git ls-remote --tags` to list the tags in the remote repository, compare and find those don't exist locally, and fetch them only one by one.